# Insert columns values in dataframe based on columns of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I originally have a dataframe `df`:

|  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Robert | 21 |
| 1 | Bob | 22 |
| 2 | Mike | 23 |

And there's also a dataframe `df2`:

|  | name | attribute | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Robert | email | robert@email.com |
| 1 | Bob | email | bob@email.com |
| 2 | Robert | married? | Yes |
| 3 | Mike | married? | No |
| 4 | Mike | employed? | Yes |
| 5 | Robert | have a car? | Yes |
| 6 | Bob | have a car? | No |

Beforehand, I already know that a person will have the attributes, for example, "age", "email", "married?", "employed?", "have a car?", "imigrant?", "student?".

How can I get a `df_final` like this:

|  | name | age | email | married? | employed? | have a car? | imigrant? | student? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Robert | 21 | robert@email.com | Yes |  | Yes |  |  |
| 1 | Bob | 22 | bob@email.com |  |  | No |  |  |
| 2 | Mike | 23 |  | No | Yes |  |  |  |

I thought about creating the attributes columns by hand in `df` and then use `df.loc[df['name']==df2['name'], df2['attribute']]` to find find the correct indexes to insert the values, but I couldn't get it right.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='name', columns='attribute', values='value')` then merge the frames together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `pivot` the second data frame, then `merge` the result to the first.  The merge is performed by matching the `'name'` column from `df` to the index (also names) of the pivoted data.

So we need to pass `left_on='name'` to use the `df.name` column, and `right_index=True` to use the index from the pivot data.

To ensure the additional columns are present, we can add them after the merge.

```
df3 = df.merge(
   df2.pivot(index='name', columns='attribute', values='value'),
   how='left',
   left_on='name',
   right_index=True,
)

for col in ['email', 'married?', 'employed?', 'have a car?', 'imigrant?', 'student?']:
    if not col in df3:
        df3[col] = ''
```

You will end up with some NA values, which you can leave or fill with `.fillna`.

Comment: What about the attribute columns that didnt't appear on `df2` ("imigrant?", "student?") ? I'm asking this because I already know which columns needs to be on `df_final`, but I also know that not all of them will appear on `df2`.

Comment: added an update for the missing columns